# I want to find all smooth quotients of the (2,3,8) triangle group of order up to say 300000. May I know how to start?

Tags: charts, group, triangle

I want to find all regular maps of type {8,3} with up to 100000 vertices, for that I need to
find all smooth quotients of the (2,3,8) triangle group of order up to 300000. Choosing GAP would be a better option? May I know how to start ?

I have understood about triangle group, full symmetry group and automorphism of a group.